# T_SQL Variable Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable in one of my SP. I have something like this in my SP:

```
Declare @Statusid int

SELECT @Statusid = ID 
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1
```

But the SQL returns only one value even though it has multiple values.

When I execute the following SQL Stmt I get multiple values for ID

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1
```

How can I get multiple values by using the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can assign one value to the variable, why not use a temp table?

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE (
StatusID  INT )

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE(StatusID) SELECT ID FROM table1 a, table2 b WHERE a.col1 = b.col1
-- USE THE TABLE AND THEN REMEMBER TO DELETE IT
DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. A variable stores one value unless it's a table variable

```
DECLARE @Status TABLE (Status int)

INSERT @Status
SELECT ID 
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.col1 = b.col1
```

And use a proper JOIN please as per the ANSI-92 standard promulgated in **1992**

Comment: LOL boy are we on the same page. Thanks for fixing my typo BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - a variable can contain only one value unless is is a table variable.
What are you doing with the variable? Why not just join to the tables?

(Also, please never use that implied join syntax again, it is a very poor programming practice that leads to errors and is more difficult to maintain.)

Answer (score 1):

The variable @Statusid may only have one value. It is likely storing the last very last value. To see this a little better try the following

```
DECLARE @Statuses varchar(max)

SELECT  @Statuses = @Statuses + cast(ID as varchar) + ", "
FROM table1 a
     INNER JOIN table2 b
     ON a.col1 = b.col1

Print @Statuses
```

As for this question

> How can I get multiple values by using the variable.

What are you planning on the variable for?